# Discord bot: Fix ‘FFMPEG not found’

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, discord, discord.js

I want to make my Discord bot join voice chat but every time I make it I get a error into log(cmd) saying, `FFMPEG not found`, please help me.

**Picture of the error:**

[image]

**This is the code:**

```
client.on('message', message => {
  // Voice only works in guilds, if the message does not come from a guild,
  // we ignore it
  if (!message.guild) return;

  if (message.content === '/join') {
    // Only try to join the sender's voice channel if they are in one themselves
    if (message.member.voiceChannel) {
      message.member.voiceChannel.join()
        .then(connection => { // Connection is an instance of VoiceConnection
          message.reply('I have successfully connected to the channel!');
        })
        .catch(console.log);
    } else {
      message.reply('You need to join a voice channel first!');
    }
  }
});
```

**this is my package.json file:**

```
{
  "name": "xxxtentacion",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^11.4.2",
    "dotenv": "^6.2.0",
    "ffmpeg": "0.0.4",
    "opusscript": "0.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `package.json`?  Do you have any ffmpeg related dependencies in that file?

Answer (score 4):

**Introduction to Voice**
Voice in discord.js can be used for many things, such as music bots, recording or relaying audio.

In discord.js, you can use voice by connecting to a VoiceChannel to obtain a VoiceConnection, where you can start streaming and receiving audio.

To get started, make sure you have:

FFmpeg - *`npm install ffmpeg-binaries`*
an opus encoder, choose one from below:

- *`npm install node-opus`* (better performance)
- *`npm install opusscript`* (a good network connection)

The preferred opus engine is node-opus, as it performs significantly better than opusscript. When both are available, discord.js will automatically choose node-opus. Using opusscript is only recommended for development environments where node-opus is tough to get working. For production bots, using node-opus should be considered a necessity, especially if they're going to be running on multiple servers.

Comment: @zero298 i added my package.json file

Answer (score 4):

[**FFmpeg**](https://ffmpeg.org/) is a convenient tool to work with audio/video/image/subtitle stuff, in this context this tool is required for extracting audio from an arbitrary container for bitstream (eg. mp4, mkv, flv, ogg) to a discord compatible VoIP codec [OPUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opus_(audio_format)).

Though it's intended be platform independent but for each platform requires different procedures, Note that: I only listed those platforms with which I have expertise with.

#### GNU/Linux

You mostly use the package manager to install it along with its dependencies, or you can just use the way of manually compiling the code with the steps described at [here](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/INSTALL.md).

```sh
# Ubuntu / Debian / Linux Mint
sudo apt install ffmpeg

# ArchLinux / Manjaro / Anarchy
sudo pacman -S ffmpeg

# Gentoo / Funtoo
USE=opus sudo emerge ffmpeg
```

### Windows

Windows is not easy as GNU/Linux, you either manually satisfy all dependencies then compile all the stuff all by yourself with MSVC or use Cygwin or Msys2 to compile. <s>An alternative way is to download pre-compiled windows binaries from [Zeranoe](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com)'s website.</s> Due to [Zeranoe](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com)'s website is closed, download from [Gyan](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/)'s website or anywhere else.

[image]

<s>This will download you a Zip archive which you've to extract and copy all contents of the `bin/` folder, those are the FFmpeg binaries. Optionally, store them at a file path which is listed in the *PATH* environment variable, to run it simply as `ffmpeg` in a shell.</s>

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with playing stream in Discord.js even thought I installed ffmpeg, so here's a possible fix, atleast in windows if **ffmpeg** command can't be run alone in CMD, then I went to node_modules\prism-media\src\core\FFmpeg.js on line 115 and there is an array of each possible directory of what to use e.g ffmpeg, so I changed from

```
}, 'ffmpeg', 'avconv', './ffmpeg', './avconv'];
```

to

```
}, 'ffmpeg', 'avconv', './ffmpeg', 'C:/ffmpeg/ffmpeg', './avconv'];
```

and it worked fine! :>